# Storing facebook friend list in coredata?

Tags: ios, facebook, core-data

I am developing an app that uses a users facebook friends for some sort of interaction.
Now I am using core data to store some user data and I am not sure whether I would like to store the users friend in the database as well for caching.

It's a speed over storage kind of situation as storage-wise it's O(n) storage over connection speed fetching each time the friends list and then manipulating it as I need to.

Of course there has to be a handler to check if the friend list got bigger or smaller but let's assume that I have that validation happening lazily and in the background while the application loads.

Any thoughts would it be wise to save it to the core data database or should I just be fetching it and re-populating the database every time the application runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is for thoughts pertaining to what is "wise" in this situation.  Actually, my answer is the same for every situation.

Write code that is simple for humans to understand.

Then, do lots of performance analysis to determine where you may need to focus on performance.  Fortunately, XCode ships with a pretty nice tool for that purpose (Instruments).

So, IMO, it would be size to implement it in the way that is the easiest and most straight-forward.  Then run performance analysis.  Address the needs that the performance tools tell you need to be addressed.